# I have to enable `hl-todo-mode` in LaTeX-mode?

Tags: todo, tex

Currenty I am on `LaTeX-mode-hook` and added following line `global-hl-todo-mode` into `.emacs` file to use [hl-todo](https://github.com/tarsius/hl-todo). On its readme it says:

> To highlight keywords turn on `hl-todo-mode` in individual buffers or use the the global variant `global-hl-todo-mode`.

My setup:

```
; L A T E X ;
(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'hl-todo-mode)
(require 'tex)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
  (global-hl-todo-mode t)  ; <= added here
  ))

(global-hl-todo-mode 1) ; <= added bottom of the page
```

---

When I open `emacs -nw file.tex`, I need to disable and than re-enable `global-hl-todo-mode` in order to use it. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Please note that, this was working perfectly fine in `python-mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with AUCTeX and [fic-mode](https://github.com/lewang/fic-mode). It's caused by the style-hooks executed by AUCTeX after loading the file. You can enable your minor mode in the `TeX-update-style-hook`, see. this [TeX stackexchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272320/emacs-auctex-preserve-highlights-from-other-modes-after-apply-style-hooks).

Comment: Adding `(add-hook 'TeX-update-style-hook 'hl-todo-mode)` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: do you want `hl-todo-mode` to be turned on for *every* mode that is allowed by `hl-todo-include-mode` (by default that is `prog-mode` and `text-mode`) except for the excluded modes in `hl-todo-exclude-mode` (by default, `org-mode`)? OR you just want it turned on for `LaTeX-mode`?

If the former, then add

```
(global-hl-todo-mode)
```

in your init file (`.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`).

If you only want it for LaTeX-mode, then add

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'hl-todo-mode)
```

to your init file.

EDIT in response to the OP's comment:

Something else is interfering. Try with `emacs -q -l minimal.el` where `minimal.el` does the following:

```
(add-to-list `load-path "/path/to/hl-todo-mode.el")
(load-library "hl-todo-mode")
(global-hl-todo-mode)
```

and then open a `tex` file and type `TODO`: it should be properly fontified with the following text properties (which you can check with `C-u C-x =` while your cursor is on that word):

```
  face                 (:inherit hl-todo :foreground "#cc9393")
  fontified            t
```

Assuming that that is the case (as it is in my tests), there is something in your init file that breaks this: bisect through it to determine what is doing the breakage.

Comment: I want `hl-todo-mode` to be turned on for *every* mode. Currently I am only using `LaTeX-mode`, `python-mode` and `markdown-mode`. I have added `(global-hl-todo-mode)` but it did not work on the `LaTeX-mode`. I have to disable and re-enable to make it work.